# Explanation of Boot Message

Tags: boot

While booting Ubuntu 16.04 I got the following message for the first time. That message was displayed 2 times and the booting was a lot slower than usual. What is the problem and why did that happen?

```
/dev/sda1: recovering journal
/dev/sda1: Clearing orphaned inode 49910977 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100664, size=16773)
/dev/sda1: Clearing orphaned inode 49909604 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100664, size=32768)
/dev/sda1: Clearing orphaned inode 49909603 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100600, size=31780)
/dev/sda1: Clearing orphaned inode 49909500 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100640, size=85)
/dev/sda1: Clearing orphaned inode 49918132 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100664, size=16773)
/dev/sda1: Clearing orphaned inode 49917725 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100664, size=16773)
/dev/sda1: Clearing orphaned inode 49917436 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100664, size=16773)
/dev/sda1: Clearing orphaned inode 49909685 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100600, size=262144)
/dev/sda1: Clearing orphaned inode 3939849 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100664, size=8192)
/dev/sda1: Clearing orphaned inode 49909471 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100664, size=16773)
/dev/sda1: Clearing orphaned inode 49909480 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100664, size=16773)
/dev/sda1: Clearing orphaned inode 49905527 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100664, size=16773)
/dev/sda1: clean, 333655/60911568 files, 7757819/243171328 blocks
```

Comment: See also ["What is an orphaned inode?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290116/what-is-an-orphaned-inode).

Answer (score 2):

Your disk wasn't unmounted correctly at last shut-down, maybe because you cut the power instead of shutting down normally. The io's that was pending at the time of shut-down has to be replayed from the journal, and leftover inodes and datablocks in the filesystem has to be cleared.